# how to sum vlaues in dataframes based on index match

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have about 16 dataframes representing weekly users' clickstream data.  The photos show the samples for weeks from 0-3. I want to make a new dataframe in this way: for example if a new df is w=2, then w2=w0+w1+w2. For w3, w3=w0+w1+w2+3. As you can see the datasets do not have identical id_users, but id a user does not show in a certain week. All dataframes have the same columns, but indexes are not exactly same. So how to add based on the logic where indexes match?

```
id_user c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11
43284   1   8   0   8   5   0   0   0   2   3   1
45664   0   16  0   4   0   0   0   0   5   16  2
52014   0   0   0   5   4   0   0   0   0   2   2
53488   1   37  0   19  0   0   3   0   3   23  6
60135   0   124 0   87  3   0   24  0   8   19  14

id_user c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11
40419   0   8   0   3   4   0   6   0   1   6   0
43284   1   4   0   14  26  2   0   0   2   4   2
45664   0   9   0   15  11  0   0   0   1   6   14
52014   0   0   0   8   9   0   8   0   2   2   1
53488   0   2   0   4   0   0   4   0   0   0   0

id_user c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10 c11
40419   0   8   0   3   4   0   6   0   1   6   0
43284   1   4   0   14  26  2   0   0   2   4   2
45664   0   9   0   15  11  0   0   0   1   6   14
52014   0   0   0   8   9   0   8   0   2   2   1
53488   0   2   0   4   0   0   4   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` then `groupby` `sum`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('id_user',as_index=False).sum()
Out[147]: 
   id_user  c1   c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11
0    40419   0    8   0   3   4   0   6   0   1    6    0
1    43284   2   12   0  22  31   2   0   0   4    7    3
2    45664   0   25   0  19  11   0   0   0   6   22   16
3    52014   0    0   0  13  13   0   8   0   2    4    3
4    53488   1   39   0  23   0   0   7   0   3   23    6
5    60135   0  124   0  87   3   0  24   0   8   19   14
```

Comment: I used the following to get dataframes. user_total_by_week Users_Summary_=pd.pivot_table(combined_df, index=['WEEK','id_user'], columns='activity_type',values=clicks; aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0). after this, I extracted each df by using user_total_by_week.loc[1] for getting w1. Then I applied your above way to get a wn. I wonder if I am doing redundant work?. Maybe there is a way I can do that easly and shorty?